# Inconsistent outputs for the same input tensors in CNN-LSTM deep learning architecture. Am I missing something?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have tried to add an LSTM layer to this 3DCNN intended to be used for video classification.

I am very new to this, and the model seems to be having some issue. I ran a dummy tensor value through the model and am getting inconsistent results for the same input. Why is this happening?

The model's **init** and forward methods are as follows:

```
def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.conv_layer1 = self._make_conv_layer(3, 64, (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2))
        self.conv_layer2 = self._make_conv_layer(64, 128, (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2))
        self.conv_layer3 = self._make_conv_layer(128, 256, (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2))
        self.conv_layer4 = self._make_conv_layer(256, 256, (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2))

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(256, 128, batch_first=True)

        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(256, 512)
        self.fc5_act = nn.ELU()
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv_layer1(x)
        x = self.conv_layer2(x)
        x = self.conv_layer3(x)
        x = self.conv_layer4(x)

        # reshaping for LSTM layer
        batch_size, channels, depth, height, width = x.size()
        x = x.reshape(depth, batch_size, channels * height * width)

        x, _ = self.lstm(x)

        # Flatten before fully connected layers
        x = x.reshape(batch_size, -1)

        x = self.fc5(x)
        x = self.fc5_act(x)
        x = self.fc6(x)
        return x
```

I passed the dummy values to the model using the following, but I keep getting the output as **False** after comparing the both the output tensors:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("in main")
    input_tensor = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.rand(6, 3, 18, 84, 84))
    model = Model(27) 
    output1 = model(input_tensor) 
    output2 = model(input_tensor)
    print(torch.equal(output1, output2))
```